# azure event hub capture vs custom function

Tags: azure-eventhub

we use event hub, the intent is to able to archive the inbound event data for troubleshooting/analytic reasons, understandably event hub capture built in plays the role, however looking at the price tag my boss not happy. His question is, what benifits it compares to we simply have a function to bridge the event hub to some sort of storage e.g. blob by ourself, would that justify the cost saving in long run..

I don't know how to answer this, could you please help?

Comment: What is the typical throughput in both bytes and number of messages?

Comment: about 1k msgs (each msg under 1k)  a day, faily low for now, could grow in the future as we stil piloting

Comment: How many partitions?

Comment: 3 for the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions consumption plan is billed mainly on number of executions whereas Event Hub capture is billed on number of TUs.

Here are couple things that can help to reduce Function app execution counts:

- Smaller EH partitions counts - for example, 4 partitions would deliver events in larger batches than 32 partitions would do.
- Increase batchSize in function app's config.

Since you have only 3 partitions and 1 TU traffic to process, you may probably save if you run with a function rather than capture. I recommend doing some test runs and see how many executions incurred then you can compare the hourly cost of functions app to $.10 hourly fixed cost of EH capture.

I am assuming storage side billing will probably be similar or you can even try reducing it further down by increasing batching and decreasing number of storage calls.

Comment: same to my understanding it appears the capture does not cater the smaller volume use cases

Comment: Correct, capture is charged at fixed rate on hourly basis even during zero traffic.